# Unable to install cocoapods in my Mac 10.13.1

Tags: objective-c, terminal, cocoapods

i am using following command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

for this i am getting following response:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to api.rubygems.org:443 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port 443) (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

i tried uninstalling  cocoapods and restart ....everything.

**upadte 1:**

i try to debug

```
gem install bundler --debug -V
```

i got following output:

```
Exception `LoadError' at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:171 - LoadError
Exception `Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError' at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:71 - Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'bundler (>= 0)'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0) in any repository
```

**Update 2:**

i changed proxys in my mac .. now i am getting :

```
 Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Comment: Seems you have internet connectivity issues

Comment: please check my update 2 @Cristik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally i found the answer:

just connected to ur personal Hotspot and use following command:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org
```

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that it was my VPN that was not allowing the download, so the incoming readers should take care of that as well.

I tried to deactivate it after I read @Cristik answer by the way.